# How to draw a UILabel border

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uilabel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CALayer: add a border only at one side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side)

I need to draw a left border of an UILabel programmatically.
Using this code it will be drawn all borders (top, left, bottom, right) around the label.

```
myLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
```

Is there a chance to draw only left-border using QuartzCore or I need to add a subview (e.g. a UIView with small weight and background) to my UILabel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy. I have done some similar programming to add "transparent" shapes (that show the background color through a button) on a view. The 15 minute method is to:

1. create a UILabel of the appropriate size (`CGRectMake(0,0,1.5f,myLabel.frame.size.height)`) and color
2. add the label to your view (this will clip the `UIlabel` with cornerRadius, etc)
3. set the `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` | `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` to let the left border resize with myLabel and stick to the left side

I think that's about it. Should work with very little drama. If you are drawing hundreds or thousands it might be slow but for a few labels, no problem.

Enjoy,

Damien

Comment: Thank you! 
That's an interesting solution, but following the linked question I think it's easier create a CALayer then add it as a sublayer. It's easier also if you need to "extend" UILabel class with a category (e.g. UILabel+Border). Thanks for your reply again!

Comment: I agree, the linked solution offsetting the frame is more clever and will scale better. This is one thing I like about trying to answer questions - I usually learn something as well.