# UILabel : How can I change all the borders except the bottom one?

Tags: ios, uilabel, border

I know I can change a border's object with

```
item.layer.cornerRadius = floatValue;
item.layer.borderWidth = intValue;
item.layer.borderColor = colorValue;
```

But how can I only change top, left and right borders ?

Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could use* another layer to mask away the corners that you don't want to see. This has the downside that you:

- can't have a shadow
- can't have another mask (if you don't do them together)
- will loose half the border width since the border is stroked on the center of your border

If that is okay with you, here is a sample code that should get you started

```
CGFloat borderWidth = 4.0;
[[myView layer] setBorderWidth:borderWidth];

CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
// The mask needs to be filled to mask
[mask setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
// Make the masks frame smaller in height
CGRect maskFrame = CGRectInset([myView bounds], 0, borderWidth);
// Move the maskFrame to the top
maskFrame.origin.y = 0;
[mask setFrame:maskFrame];
[[myView layer] setMask:mask];
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that directly.

There are a couple of responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side) that might help, including one that links to some [open source code](https://github.com/adam-siton/AUISelectiveBordersView) that solves the problem.