# Frame.size.width Not Returning Correct UIButton Width

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, border

I am trying to add a top and right border to my button but not the bottom or left. I looked it up and found a suggestion to do so by adding views to look like borders.

```
    //Add borders
    let topBorder = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, editorBox.frame.size.width/3, 1))
    let rightBorder = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(cancel.frame.size.width, 0, 1, cancel.frame.size.height))
    topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255.0, green: 220/255.0, blue: 220/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    rightBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220/255.0, green: 220/255.0, blue: 220/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cancel.addSubview(topBorder)
    cancel.addSubview(rightBorder)
```

But the resulting Simulator test looks like:

[image: Button border size is not correct]

[image: UIButton border size not correct]

However, the button is definitely not that big because you can't click on the far right side of it. The auto layout constraints confirm that the button is not that big.

[image: Autolayout constraints]

I just want each button to have a border around it's actual 1/3 width size, as set in the constraints. Can anyone tell me what's happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the other answer didn't solve my border problem by itself. Here's the code I'm using, based on the @tbondwilkinson answer:

```
    //Add borders
    let borderColor = UIColor(red: 200/255.0, green: 200/255.0, blue: 200/255.0, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    func formatTopBorder (buttonToFormat: UIButton,borderToFormat: CALayer) {
        buttonToFormat.clipsToBounds = true
        borderToFormat.borderColor = borderColor
        borderToFormat.borderWidth = 2
        borderToFormat.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(cancel.frame), 2)
    }
    let topBorder: CALayer = CALayer()
    let topBorder2: CALayer = CALayer()
    let topBorder3: CALayer = CALayer()
    let rightBorder: CALayer = CALayer()
    let leftBorder: CALayer = CALayer()

    formatTopBorder(cancel, borderToFormat: topBorder)
    formatTopBorder(action, borderToFormat: topBorder2)
    formatTopBorder(addSave, borderToFormat: topBorder3)

    rightBorder.borderColor = borderColor
    rightBorder.borderWidth = 2
    rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(cancel.frame)-2, 0, 2, CGRectGetHeight(cancel.frame))

    leftBorder.borderColor = borderColor
    leftBorder.borderWidth = 1
    leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2, CGRectGetHeight(cancel.frame))

    cancel.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
    cancel.layer.addSublayer(rightBorder)
    action.layer.addSublayer(topBorder2)
    addSave.layer.addSublayer(topBorder3)
    addSave.layer.addSublayer(leftBorder)
```

But if placed in the viewDidLoad, it doesn't work perfectly. The top borders work and so does the left border. However, it was still prematurely getting the UIButton width, resulting in the right border not working:

```
    rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(cancel.frame)-2, 0, 2, CGRectGetHeight(cancel.frame))
```

The CGRectGetWidth(cancel.frame)-2 gets the correct right edge and gives space for the border, but it gets the width before the button has sized itself.

**The solution:**

Use the method and then put that code in the viewDidAppear. Unfortunately, the borders appear a fraction of a second after your view appears, but all the borders will be correct.

*If anyone can post code that works for a right-edge border, that runs in the viewDidLoad, please post it and I'll mark it correct.*

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me to be an autolayout issue - your button is being generated before the layout changes its width.  Your border views, on the other hand, do not get their width changed because they're outside of the constraint hierarchy.

For something this simple though, I think UIViews are a bit too much.  I would add a few CALayers to the Button in question.

Here's a stack overflow question directly relating to the CALayer solution:
[CALayer: add a border only at one side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side)

Comment: Just tried it using the code in that link. Same result! How is creating a border causing me hours of frustration!?!? This is insane!

Comment: Wait, now it works. It was showing a weird corner thing but I changed the height to 1 manually in the code and it worked. thanks