# How to remove right and left borders in UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift 2.3 now. I've added borders to the button with this code:

```
self.history.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.history.layer.borderColor = UIColor.mainColor().CGColor
```

And as a result I got:
[image: History button borders]

Now, I need to remove left and right borders and have only top and bottom borders left. How can I manage it?

Additions: thnx to @Teja, I've seen another question [CALayer: add a border only at one side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side)
But, the thing is I need bottom and top. However, after adding -1, -1 CALayer only the bottom one has been added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CALayer: add a border only at one side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side)

Comment: Use `CALayers` rather than a border

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like below.

```
let topBorder = CALayer()
topBorder.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;
topBorder.borderWidth = 1;
topBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: label.frame.width, height: 1)
label.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

let bottomBorder = CALayer()
bottomBorder.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;
bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1;
bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: label.frame.height, width: label.frame.width, height: 1)
label.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly that's what I did

Comment: This code helped a lot. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem by adding this two CALayers:

```
let bottomBorder: CALayer = CALayer()
let topBorder: CALayer = CALayer()
bottomBorder.borderColor = UIColor.mainColor().CGColor
topBorder.borderColor = UIColor.mainColor().CGColor
bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1
topBorder.borderWidth = 1
bottomBorder.frame =  CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(history.frame), CGRectGetWidth(history.frame), 1)
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(history.frame), 1)
history.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
history.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
```

Great thanks to @Teja and @Rajan!

Answer (score 1):

You can add several layers instead of border, but you cannot affect corner radius to these like border, by the way here is just add borders to your project

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    func drawBorder(edges: [UIRectEdge], borderWidth: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
        for item in edges {
            let borderLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
            borderLayer.borderColor = color.cgColor
            borderLayer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            switch item {
            case .top:
                borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: borderWidth)
            case .left:
                borderLayer.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: borderWidth, height: frame.height)
            case .bottom:
                borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.height - borderWidth, width: frame.width, height: borderWidth)
            case .right:
                borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - borderWidth, y: 0, width: borderWidth, height: frame.height)
            case .all:
                drawBorder(edges: [.top, .left, .bottom, .right], borderWidth: borderWidth, color: color)
            default:
                break
            }
            self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[SWIFT 4.2]**

I was trying to show that the bottom border to have this result :

[image]

I improved the extension of the post above to add the margins..

```
extension UIButton {

     func drawBorder(edges: [UIRectEdge], borderWidth: CGFloat, color: UIColor, margin: CGFloat) {
        for item in edges {
            let borderLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
            borderLayer.borderColor = color.cgColor
            borderLayer.borderWidth = borderWidth
            switch item {
            case .top:
                borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: 0, width: frame.width - (margin*2), height: borderWidth)
            case .left:
                borderLayer.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: margin, width: borderWidth, height: frame.height - (margin*2))
            case .bottom:
                borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: frame.height - borderWidth, width: frame.width - (margin*2), height: borderWidth)
            case .right:
                borderLayer.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - borderWidth, y: margin, width: borderWidth, height: frame.height - (margin*2))
            case .all:
                drawBorder(edges: [.top, .left, .bottom, .right], borderWidth: borderWidth, color: color, margin: margin)
            default:
                break
            }
            self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
        }
    }

}
```

Use :

```
mybutton.drawBorder(edges: [.bottom], borderWidth: 1, color: UIColor.darkGray, margin: 20)
```

It's works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to add UIView as borders with height or width as a borderWidth. You can add them all hide/show depend on your use or only add top and bottom view for it.

This is really useful if you are not programmatically creating the view and need to use constraints.