# How to create only bottom border for label?

Tags: objective-c, calayer

Hi I used the the following code to create a bottom border to my label

```
CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2;
    border.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, _label.frame.size.height - borderWidth, _label.frame.size.width, _label.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    [_label.layer addSublayer:border];
    _label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

But it the border is breaks at half of label. How can I fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boss it is working for me without any breaking. Can u attach the screen shot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CALayer: add a border only at one side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022656/calayer-add-a-border-only-at-one-side)

Comment: @MuraliMohan It is working for me too but border is not fully drawn.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

With the use of `CALayer` you can create border on `UILabel` or any other `UIControl`.

**1) Bottom Border**

```
 CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
 bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
 bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1;
 bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(myLabel.frame)-1, CGRectGetWidth(myLabel.frame), 1);
 myLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [myLabel.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

**2) Top Border**

```
 CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
 topBorder.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
 topBorder.borderWidth = 1;
 topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(myLabel.frame), 1);
 myLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [myLabel.layer addSublayer:topBorder];
```

**3) Left Border**

```
 CALayer *leftBorder = [CALayer layer];
 leftBorder.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
 leftBorder.borderWidth = 1;
 leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, CGRectGetHeight(myLabel.frame));
 myLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [myLabel.layer addSublayer:leftBorder];
```

**4) Right Border**

```
 CALayer *rightBorder = [CALayer layer];
 rightBorder.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
 rightBorder.borderWidth = 1;
 rightBorder.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(myLabel.frame)-1, 0, 1, CGRectGetHeight(myLabel.frame));
 myLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
 [myLabel.layer addSublayer:rightBorder];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

```
    CALayer* layer = [lbl layer];
    CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1;
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer.frame.size.height-1,layer.frame.size.width, 1);
    [bottomBorder setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

[image: check demo]

Comment: This also draws to half of the label.

Comment: No dude, it's draw actual width of the label, by this code
CALayer* layer = [lbl layer];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer.frame.size.height-1,layer.frame.size.width, 1)

see screenshot also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate width of label based on string and also font which you require.
You can get size like this

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                    lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

and use expectedLabelSize while setting frame for your border.

```
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, _label.frame.size.height - borderWidth, _expectedLabelSize.width , _label.frame.size.height);
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding !!

Comment: The label should wrap based on the text,but by hardcoding maximum label size how it will help?

Comment: for wrapping you need to use

Comment: for wrapping you need to use  [yourlabel sizeToFit];

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following code.

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
```

[lbl setText:@"Testo di prova..."];

[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[[self view] addSubview:lbl];

[lbl sizeToFit];

CALayer* layer = [lbl layer];

CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];

bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;

bottomBorder.borderWidth = 1;

bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(-1, layer.frame.size.height-1, layer.frame.size.width, 1);

[bottomBorder setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

[layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];